# float number conversions with ".toString" is funcional in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I convert number `1.1` to binary (or any other number base) is it possible to return it to decimal float number?

```js
console.log((1.1).toString(2));
console.log((1.1).toString(8));
console.log((1.1).toString(16));
```

Comment: That is decimal, though? What format do you want it to be in?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you would want something like `Number.parseFloat('1.01', 2)` to return `1.25` (`1.01` being binary representation of the decimal float `1.25`)? (the second arg to `parseFloat` is just something I made up, it doesn't exist AFAIK like `Number.parseInt(string, ?radix)`.

Comment: @SpenserBlack would be the conversion of a floating number from another numeric base to decimal base (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS has a few built in methods for parsing numbers. Using `parseFloat` here would be ideal, however unfortunately `parseFloat` does not allow you to specify the radix (base) under which the string should be parsed.

However, the `parseInt` function *does* let you specify the radix, but it can only work with integer numbers and will fail when trying to parse a decimal. But with a little bit of math you can parse the whole and decimal parts of your string separately, then recombine them to get the converted number.

Perhaps something like:

```js
console.log((1.1).toString(2));
console.log((1.1).toString(8));
console.log((1.1).toString(16));

function parseInBase(num_str, base) {
  const [integer_part, decimal_part] = num_str.split(".");
  const integer_part_num = parseInt(integer_part, base);
  
  if (!decimal_part) return integer_part_num;
  
  // Trim trailing zeroes:
  const sanitized_dec_part = decimal_part.replace(/0+$/, "");
  const decimal_part_num = parseInt(sanitized_dec_part, base);
  
  return integer_part_num + decimal_part_num / base**sanitized_dec_part.length;
}

console.log(parseInBase((1.1).toString(2), 2));
console.log(parseInBase((1.1).toString(8), 8));
console.log(parseInBase((1.1).toString(16), 16));
```

Comment: Is this an expression of computational mathematics? I expected it to be something dividing the parts and applying parseInt, but when the fraction returned a giant number I thought it was a floating or something. 

I also don't understand what the reason for using ``sanitized_dec_part`` is, but I think it's due to a lack of understanding of the whole.

Comment: Could you give me a reference so I can study later?

Comment: The stripping of trailing zeroes is mathematically unnecessary here, which may add to the confusion. I added it just to make sure that the denominator is as small as possible, but the result will come out the same even if you don't remove them.

Comment: This works by parsing the integer portion as normal. Then you just need to add the remaining decimal part. Note that when you write `3.14` (in base _10_), this means the same thing as `3 + 14/100` (*2* decimal places -> _10_ ^ *2* = 100). This code uses that same pattern but for an arbitrary base.